# .htaccess - Rewriting results in a 500 internal server error (ODD)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know this is a "popular" question but i'm rather sure my .htaccess file is allright. However, it still results in a 500 internal server error and i'm wondering how to fix it.

```
RewriteEngine on
CheckSpelling on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

I want to 'hide' the folder "Pages" from the URL so users can just navigate to **domain.com/mypage** instead of **domain.com/pages/mypage**.

Without the *RewriteCond* and the *RewriteRule*  the .htaccess file works.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: did u run this before ? `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Apache Webserver has not `mod_speling` enabled.
Your htaccess looks fine.

Try remove the line `CheckSpelling on` if it is not necessary or install `mod speling` and enable it with `a2enmod speling`

As Hiren patel allready pointed out, check that `mod rewrite` is enabled too. `a2enmod rewrite`